How can I transfer data between the application target and the UI test target?
I have an application that needs to be tested (UI). The application uses different feature configurations, and I'm looking for a convenient way to turn features on/off for proper testing. What are reliable and convenient ways to transfer information to the target application?
I know that it is possible to transfer information via ProcessInfo, but due to some circumstances, I am more interested in the possibility of using the simulator's file system. How correct would it be to write data to the simulator's cache and then read it from the application?
Here is one of the ways that I found:
func write() {
  let sharedResourcesDir = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_SHARED_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY"]!
  let cachesDir = URL(fileURLWithPath: sharedResourcesDir).appendingPathComponent("Library/Caches")

  // creating a folder and writing / reading data
}

Are there any risks of using this approach?

You would typically mock the class that provides the current feature set and inject that mock with whatever features you need to test enabled.

And you would design the application to be testable.

Unfortunately Xcode UI Tests are terrible in that way, Apple didn't design them with a way to inject mock content, so you'd either have to setup everything in your main code and then pass a command line flag, or use a different form of UI testing (highly recommend this instead, as the UI testing framework is super bad)
